# ORA-00905: missing keyword due to multiple CASE Conditions

Tags: oracle, case

I m getting`missing keyword` error due to multiple CASE WHEN logic. Below is my code

```
select inv.ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM as CMM_APPROVED_LENGTH, inv.SPAN_TYPE,  ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4) AS NE_LENGTH, 
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS UG_LENGTH
,ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY LIKE '%AERIAL%' THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4) AS AR_LENGTH,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%' OR RJ_CONSTRUCTION_METHODOLOGY IS  NULL THEN NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0) ELSE 0 END)/1000,4)/ ROUND(SUM(NVL(CALCULATED_LENGTH,0)/1000),4)*100 as ug_percentage
,mv.rj_intracity_link_id  FROM NE.MV_SPAN@DB_LINK_NE_VIEWER mv
join TBL_FIBER_INV_CMP_REPORT_MV inv
on   (CASE WHEN  inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'INTERCITY' THEN inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_span_id ELSE END)
      CASE WHEN inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'INTRACITY' THEN inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_intracity_link_id ELSE END)
      CASE WHEN inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'ENTERPRISE' THEN inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_intracity_link_id ELSE END)
GROUP BY mv.rj_intracity_link_id, inv.ROUTE_APPROVED_BY_CMM, inv.SPAN_TYPE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `ELSE END` without anything in between, but you also can't have a condition to evaluate as the `WHEN` or `ELSE` clause.

You can use Boolean logic rather than case expressions:

```
join TBL_FIBER_INV_CMP_REPORT_MV inv
on   ((inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'INTERCITY' AND inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_span_id)
   or (inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'INTRACITY' AND inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_intracity_link_id)
   or (inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'ENTERPRISE' AND inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_intracity_link_id))
```

Comment: its just taking `AND` but if my first condition satisfies `inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'INTERCITY'` then what ?? will it take `inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_span_id` for updation ?

Comment: Yes, it will match if `inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'INTERCITY'` AND `inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_span_id`; OR if one of the other pairs of conditions is matched. Only one (at most) can be true tor each row, as `SPAN_TYPE` can't be more than one value at a time. If `inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'INTERCITY'` then it *won't* look at `inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_intracity_link_id`, because of the parentheses around the AND pairs.

Comment: So suppose, if `inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'INTERCITY'` then it will take `inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_span_id` to select or update as column. because as from your answer you are checking two conditions and I am checking one

Comment: Yes; but not sure about the two/one thing, your original case expression was trying to do the same thing, just with broken logic. (Tony's approach is logically the same too.)

Comment: Depends if it's about this answer, or should be a new question...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a condition (Boolean) from a CASE like this:

```
CASE WHEN inv.SPAN_TYPE = 'INTRACITY' THEN inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = mv.rj_intracity_link_id ELSE END
```

Instead you can use a CASE expression like this:

```
ON inv.SPAN_LINK_ID = CASE inv.SPAN_TYPE
                         WHEN 'INTERCITY' THEN mv.rj_span_id
                         WHEN 'INTRACITY' THEN mv.rj_intracity_link_id
                         WHEN 'ENTERPRISE' THEN mv.rj_intracity_link_id
                         END
```

Comment: @hud - that suggests one of `rj_span_id` and `rj_intracity_link_id` is `varchar2` and the other is `nvarchar2`? Which sounds a bit odd.